# chrome.tabs.sendMessage after chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a new chrome extension to transfer the data received in the `responseHeaders` to the current tab, in order to display them on the web page.

For this, I use the `chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived` listener to retrieve and parse the data. After that, I would like to transfer this information via `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` but it doesn't work.

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    [...]
    "background": { 
        "scripts": ["js/background.js"],
        "persistent": true
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
          "css": ["css/style.css"],
          "js": ["js/jquery.js", "js/content.js"]
        }
      ],
    "permissions": [
        "background", 
        "webRequest",
        "tabs",
        "activeTab",
        "<all_urls>"
    ]
}
```

**background.js**

```js
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
    chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(function(response){
        response.responseHeaders.forEach(element => {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, element);  
        });
     },{
       urls: [
         "<all_urls>"
       ]
     },["responseHeaders"]);
});
```

**content.js**

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener (function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    alert("Message received");
});
```

By executing this code, the alert is never triggered.

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alert message in content.js file will alarm when getting messages. To send message in background file chrome tabs.query should execute onHeadersReceived event. But seems places of tabs.query and webRequest.onHeadersReceived are changed. The order is that background.js get a request from the url and access tabs query to send message.

**background.js**

```js
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(function(response){
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
            response.responseHeaders.forEach(element => {
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, element);  
            });
        });
     },{
       urls: [
         "<all_urls>"
       ]
     },["responseHeaders"]);
```

Comment: No need for chrome.tabs.query at all because the response isn't necessarily in the active tab. Use `response.tabId`.